# How to add a binary status variable based on the change of 2 variables in separate rows in Python Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a binary status variable (0/1) based on the change in value of 2 variables in separate rows. My dataset is has the below format:

```
    Repo  Count    Push     Status (would like to add)
0   123   0         0
1   123   7         50
2   123   8         55
3   123   9         57

df = pd.DataFrame({"Repo":[123,123,123,123], "Count":[0,7,8,9], "Push":[0,50,55,57]})
```

Based on the above dataset, if push = 0 and the difference between "count" from row "0" to row "1" is more than 6, then status will equal 1; otherwise, status equals 0. In this example, status for row "0" should be 1.

Any advice will be much appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use lambda functions

Comment: Better code than picture. Also when working of dataframe, could please share the data as a dict, or format which can be reusable by us to test ?

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour.  Where is your coding attempt?  Look up how to compare adjacent rows with the `shift` method; look up how to create a new column; post the code as a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `df` ist your dataframe:

```
# create a mask
mask = (df.Count.diff().shift(-1) > 6) & (df.Push == 0)
# create a column Status which is 0 everywhere
df['Status'] = 0
# set Status to 1 where mask is True
df.loc[mask, 'Status'] = 1
```

Short explanation of `mask`: Create a boolean index mask which is `True` where your conditions are met.
`df.Count.diff().shift(-1)` gives you the differences between each row in `Count`. `shift(-1)` shifts the results by one row, so that the difference is assigned to the "starting" row.
`df.Push == 0` checks if Push is zero.

Comment: Scotty, not sure if you can help with this one, but I am trying to add rows where there is a gap between month_count. For example, row 0 has month_count = 0 and row 1 has month_count = 7. How can I add extra 6 rows with month counts being 1,2,3,4,5,6 and the rest of the column values being 0? My dataset has over 1000 rows and there are gaps like that everywhere. Any advice is much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you please open a new question and show a detailed example of what your dataframe looks like? It is quite hard to solve this just from an unformatted comment.